# jQuery(this).clearQueue is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("ul.logos-sprite-icon-wrap li a.logos-icon").hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).animate({
      'padding-top': '0px',
      'padding-bottom': '5px',
    }, 500);
  }, function() {
    jQuery(this).clearQueue();
    jQuery(this).clearQueue().animate({
      'padding-top': '5px',
      'padding-bottom': '0px',
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

then after i use jQuery `share-basket-icon` plugins then the error was come to...

`jQuery(this).clearQueue` is not a function

```
jQuery(this).clearQueue();
```

Comment: Please use the `{}` button to format sample code in a monospace font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: see comments; this is totally wrong. However, since this was added in 1.4, is it possible that you're using an older version of jQuery?

It looks like `clearQueue` is indeed not a function, but a parameter to `.stop()`:

> `.stop( [ clearQueue ], [ jumpToEnd ] )`
>
> `clearQueue` - A Boolean indicating whether
>   to remove queued animation as well.
>   Defaults to false.
>
> `jumpToEnd` - A Boolean indicating whether
>   to complete the current animation
>   immediately. Defaults to false.

http://api.jquery.com/stop

Comment: no! since jQuery 1.4, [clearQueue](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/) is already there as a function..

Comment: I went to http://docs.jquery.com/ and typed in `clearQueue` and only http://api.jquery.com/stop came up. What's the difference between docs.jquery.com and api.jquery.com?